# Use DBEngine with Run-time Access

Tags: vba, excel, dao

i try to connect my xls with access database. Below code work greate when i have installed full access program on my machine. Problem is when i try tu use it on machine what have only installed Run-time version of access.

I have use this references:

```
Visual Basic For Applications
Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library
OLE Automation
Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library
Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library
```

When i try to run below code i get error: *ActiveX component can't create object or return reference to this object (Error 429)*

```
Sub mcGetPromoFromDB()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim daoDB            As DAO.Database
    Dim daoQueryDef      As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim daoRcd           As DAO.Recordset

    'Error on line below
    Set daoDB = Application.DBEngine.OpenDatabase("K:\DR04\Groups\Functional\DC_Magazyn\Sekcja_Kontroli_Magazynu\Layout\dbDDPiZ.accdb")
    Set daoRcd = daoDB.OpenRecordset("kwPromoIDX", dbOpenDynaset)

    Dim tempTab() As Variant

    For Each Article In collecArticle
        daoRcd.FindNext "IDX = " & Article.Index
        Article.PromoName = daoRcd.Fields(1).Value
        Article.PromoEnd = "T" & Format(daoRcd.Fields(2).Value, "ww", vbMonday, vbUseSystem)
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You really ought to be setting a DAO reference if you're going to early bind that code. If it doesn't work without Access installed, you could switch to ADO instead.

Comment: Ok, i try to use ADO instead but it is very slow, there is any way to speed up this code? I use    <pre><code>rsADO.Find "Indeks = " & Article.Index, 0, adSearchForward, 1 to lookup in the recordsets.</code></pre>

Comment: Have you tried filtering instead? Or only returning the records that match your criteria rather than the whole table, so you have fewer records to search?

Comment: I tried now but i dont see any difrance. Problem is that i have to look for 6k records in 120k query.

Answer (score 0):

Is IDX an indexed field?

Is `kwPromoIDX` optimized for this specific purpose?  I mean does it only contain the fields required for this update, or are you pulling extra useless fields?  Perhaps something like "`SELECT IDX, [Field1Name], [Field2Name] FROM kwPromoIDX`" would be more efficient.

Since you are only reading the table records, and don't seem to need to actually edit them instead of `dbOpenDynaset`, use `dbOpenSnapshot`.

Just throwing out an idea here, you'd have to test to see if it made any difference, but perhaps you could try to reverse your logic. Loop through the recordset 1 by 1 and locate the IDX within your worksheet.

Another thing I've done in the past is use `.CopyFromRecordset` and copied the entire recordset into a temporary worksheet and done the juggling back and forth entirely within Excel, to eliminate the back and forth.

Lastly, another approach can be to quickly loop through the entire recordset and populate an array, collection, ... and then work with it instead of Access.  This way the data is all virtual and you reduce the back and forth with Access.

You'll need to do some testing to see what works best in your situation.